# What is gij (GNU libgcj) java?

Tags: java

Today I checked `update-alternatives --config java` and got a weird output:

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gij-4.8                          1048      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.8                          1048      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   3         manual mode
```

I've never seen this `/usr/bin/gij-4.8` before. What is that?
Has it been installed by some package? How to find out which?

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.8.4

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The strange thing is that I use Java only on Firefox for banking and it runs well. It shows that I have the latest Oracle java installed.

Is that a malware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that? Has it been installed by some package? How to find out
>   which?

`gij` is a Java bytecode interpreter included with `libgcj` package. `libgcj` is the runtime that goes along with the [`gcj`](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/gcj2.html) front end to GCC and includes parts of the Java Class Libraries, plus glue to connect the libraries to the compiler and the underlying OS. So, not a malware definitely.

References:

[The libgcj home page](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/libgcj2.html)

[SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107870/is-gij-gnu-interpreter-for-java-stable-enough-for-commercial-use)